# Incorrect datetime value: '31-01-2013' for column 'user_date' at row 1

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query_insert = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pass, user_email, user_date, user_level, user_posts)
                        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$insert = $mysqli->prepare($query_insert);
                $insert->bind_param("ssssii", $username, $password_enc, $email, $date, $level_start, $post_start);
                $insert->execute();
$date = date('d-m-Y');
```

Those are the related parts. The only thing is...when i execute this it doesnt add to the table

I had a look around and someone said to have $insert->error; so I put that in and this came up

```
Incorrect datetime value: '31-01-2013' for column 'user_date' at row 1
```

Anybody able to help?

Comment: Should be `'2013-01-31'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to be `2013-01-31`, i.e. `date('Y-m-d')`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: @Deggerz what do you mean by show it?  Like when you SELECT it?  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(user_date, '%m-%d-%Y') ...`

Answer (score 1):

when inserting value on `date` data type, it should be on the following format `yyyy-MM-dd`, so in your example date, it should `2013-01-31`.

Don't worry about the pattern of dates when saved on the database. Leave it as is. If you are concern about the formatting, then you can do it during your projection of the data by using such function called `DATE_FORMAT`.

- [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)